# Calculator gives a different answer than online math websites - exponents

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

I am quite confused with the different answers obtained when I inputed an equation into a physical calculator and an online math calculator. The equation was:

(6.67×10e-11)×(5.97×10e24)×(7.35×10e22)÷(3.82×10e8)^2

The physical calculator gave me an answer of 2.005676...×10e21.
Whereas the online math calculator gave me an answer of 2.005676...×10e20.

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

P.S. I used a casio and kenko calculator for my physical calculator and mathway.com for my online calculator.

Comment: What exactly did you enter?

Answer (score 1):

Copying your query into WolframAlpha reveals the issue:

> Input interpretation:
> $$(6.67×10×10^{-11}) (5.97×10×10^{24})×\frac{7.35×10×10^{22}} {(3.82×10×10^8)^2}$$

It interpreted $10e24$ as $10\times 10^{24}$, which is $10^{25}$, or $e25$.

If you interpret $10ex$ as $10^x$ then you get the smaller result. WolframAlpha (and I) interpret $ex$ as $10^x$.